# How to take top 10 when lazy loading multiple levels in EF7

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

As an example, I have a simple domain model of *Customer* > *Orders* and *Order* > *Orderlines*.

I want to obtain a list of all customers each with the last most recent 10 orders including their order lines.

The following LINQ does not work (this is not a complete surprise), but what should be the correct syntax, if at all possible?

```
var customers = _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.Orders)
                 .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDateTime)
                 .Take(10)
                 .ThenInclude(c => c.OrderLines);
```

The SQL generated takes the TOP(10) from Customers (rather than the TOP(10) from Orders). And then ORDERBY DESC from the final result. So the OrderByDescending and the Take(10) is applied to Customers not Orders.

**UPDATE**

The following code (without the ThenInclude)

```
var customers = _context.Customers
                 .Include(c => c.Orders)
                 .OrderByDescending(c => c.Created)
                 .Take(10)
```

generates the following SQL..

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[CreatedDateTime], [a].[CustomerID]
FROM [Order] AS [a]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) [c].[CreatedDateTime], [c].[Id]
    FROM [Customer] AS [c]
) AS [c] ON [a].[CustomerID] = [c].[Id] ORDER BY [c].[CreatedDateTime] DESC, [c].[Id]
```

Which clearly is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Define "does not work". What _does_ it do?

Comment: I should have posted the generated SQL. I'll go back to it and see if I can add to the question. I have added a summary of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am obviously not able to test this but wouldn't you need to use Count?

```
var customers = _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.Orders)
                 .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDateTime)
                 .ThenInclude(c => c.OrderLines).Take(10);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand that one Chris. Let me edit my post to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var customers = from n in _context.Customers
                    select
                        new
                        {
                            n,
                            Orders = _context.Orders.Where(l => l.CustomeId == 
                             n.CustomeId).OrderByDescending(l => l.Date).Take(10)
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, yes this does work but returns anonymous class objects rather than Customers and x2 hits to the database. I could create a single query for this in SQL, I just would like to do this in code. I'll investigate further. It may be that what I am looking for isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the ordering and TOP to the Orders, so call the methods on Orders instead of Customers:

```
var customers = _context.Customers
        .Include(c => c.Orders
             .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDateTime)
             .Take(10)
             .Include(c => c.OrderLines));
```

Comment: Tried this Rik and it throws: "Unable to cast object of type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'."

Comment: Yeah I just found out subqueries (except for select) don't work in an include. I'm working on a new approach.

Comment: I guess I could separately add range but this would require two db hits I presume...